# Update rows in MySQL, replacing every second <p> with </p>

Tags: mysql

I have a column which store htmls, i.e.

```
<p>abc<p>...<p>xyz<p>
```

I need to add a `/` to every `<p>` tag pair, i.e.

```
<p>abc</p>...<p>xyz</p>
```

Is it possible to achieve this in MySQL? I only need to update `<p>` tags.

Comment: This is not a simple operation in SQL.  You could write a stored function to manipulate the string.

Comment: it is not clear whether your data is like this : <p>abc<p><p>bcd<p>.... <p>xyz<p> or like this <p>abc<p>bcd<p>. pls clarify

Comment: @objectNotFound it's a bunch of html `p` tags, for example `<p>text<p><p>different text<p><p>other text<p>`

Answer (score 0):

> it's a bunch of html p tags, for example `<p>text<p><p>different`
>   `text<p><p>other text<p>`

**If** there are 2 (and only 2) consecutive`<p>` tags in the string (except for the outer 2 tags)

Then

- Add an extra `<p>` tag at the end
- Then simple Replace function that will replace `<p><p>` with
  `</p><p>`

  ```
  Declare @mystring = orig_string + <p>
  Select REPLACE(@mystring, '<p><p>', '</p><p>')
  ```

Comment: @Barmar Iam adding an extra p tag at the end before replacing (and I also fixed the typo in the replacement string made it </p><p> instead of <p></p>